# How to exec command in chroot filesystem

Tags: c, linux, chroot

In my system, i create a new filesystem contains all file, then i try exec command like

`chroot /new_root_path /bin/bash -c "echo a > a"`

I found file a write to new filesystem root path, but i try to exec command like this, and i think different

`chroot /new_root_path /bin/bash -c "hostname > a"`

the a file content is not new filesystem‘s hostname different from new filesystem /etc/hostname, file content is old filesystem‘s hostname

how can i exec command such as hostname or other command in new filesystem‘s /bin or /sbin

I found similar questions in stackoverflow, but did't found conclusion

Comment: I miss the reason for tagging this question "C". What help do you ope to get from C experts?

Comment: In total I suspect that the question would have better chances on SuperUser.

Comment: Please review the second shown code fragment. I suspect you are missing a `"`.

Comment: @Yunnosch In fact, I hope to realize this function through c. I don’t know if there are any friends who realize similar needs, so I added it to the tag.

Comment: I do not see anything in your question which seems a programming attempt. At least not one with a compiled language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute `hostname` everywhere. But since it's tagged C, you could also call `gethostname()`. That tells you why you see what you see: you're asking the kernel. It's the same kernel, so you get the same answer.

`/etc/hostname` is used to call `sethostname()` on startup, and it uses the file content at that moment. It's not necessarily the same at any moment in time, even without a chroot.

Comment: I seem to understand that chroot actually just switches the root directory and executes the hostname command, and it will not change due to the change of the root directory. Can you understand it like this?

Comment: @FlagT yes.....

Comment: @FlagT: Correct, the `hostname` command uses the kernel, not the filesystem, so it doesn't care about the root of the filesystem.